# Can I call functions of an Excel addin in C# project?

Tags: c#, xll

The Excel addin is written in C++, but I don't have the source code.

I can use its functions on a Excel spreadsheet; can I do the same in C#?

Solved:

Thanks all, it works by the following code:

```
excelFile = new Excel.Application();
//Set XLL path
excelFile.RegisterXLL("XLL Path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your XLL managed or unmanaged code?

As far as I know, an unmanaged C++ XLL file is in fact a DLL that exports specific methods called by Excel.

If your XLL has a .def file, maybe you could add method that would be called by the other team.

Comment: the XLL is compiled, and I don't have a .def file

Comment: then also you can export specific methods, but if you haven't .def file then you won't add any method there